# array deepcopy instead of reference in perl object

Tags: perl, object, reference, deep-copy

i tried several hours to store a sub array into an object and failed. maybe someone of you can show me how to store a deep copy with perl.
sry i dont know if this question is clear, but should be easy to solve...

here the example.

here the object class

```
package obj;

use strict;
use warnings;
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);

sub new(\@){
    my $class=shift;
    my $this={};
    $this->{"array"}=shift;
    return bless($this,$class);
}

sub getArray(){
    my $this=shift;
    return $this->{"array"};
}
```

and the test class

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use obj;

my @a=(1,2);
push @a,3;
my $ob=obj->new(\@a);
@a=();
print @{$ob->getArray()};
```

this returns nothing - does not shift dereference the array?

so how to do this?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deference what array? The only array involved in the shift is `@_`? `$_[0]` is a scalar, not an array.

A (shallow) array copy is done using:

```
@dst = @src;
```

so you want

```
@{ $this->{"array"} } = @{ shift };
```

If you truly want an deep copy (though there's no need for it in your example), use

```
use Storable qw( dclone );

$this->{"array"} = dclone(shift);
```

Comment: or do a shallow copy by: `$this->{'array'} = [ @{ shift } ]`

Comment: if i do this, the output will become a scalar and and it returns only the first array element 1. i think that a deep copy is necessary because i overwrite @a=(). so the referenced array is gone. use Storable qw( dclone ); do what i want. thx

Comment: @pyr0, I don't know if you are referring to my code or ysth, but neither copies a single element of the array.